# Create ssh root password

Tags: ssh, centos, plesk

For some reason, after a plesk update, I can no longer login to ssh as root using my old password. I have tried to create a user with:

> /bin/bash & /bin/bash (chrooted) in plesk

Which lets me login but has no root privileges. How can I either recover my old password or get access to the ssh config to check whether root login is disabled. I installed ssh term in plesk, but that bums out with an error of:

> jarsigning exception

Guess it's because there is only the default certificate on the server. I would be grateful if someone could help with this as I have reached a point where I am struggling to find other things to try. Many thanks

Plesk 11.5 CentOS 6 SSH Client

Answer (score 0):

Once you are logged with the non-root user try to type "su" or "su root" and the enter your root password, it will allow you to become root.

Note that su allow you to login as any user, the syntax is "su username".

Comment: It will not allow me to become root. errors with: su: incorrect password
if i do su user and put in correct password it just drops to bash shell and still no root access. Thanks